# How to get Nested Gson keys (not values of keys) from Hashmap

Tags: java, android

My requirement is collect both the keys and values of keys from json and print it in list view as key value,so there will be no pre defined keys.

I have a nested object called as ListDetailModel, in that there are several other objects of other Pojo classes.

Right now I am able to derive the keys of parent object that is ListDetailModel.

My question is how to derive the keys of nested Pojos from the same entry set object. What I know is I can make separate objects for the required Pojo classes and derive keys.But can I do it from same class?

```
Map<String,ListDetailModel> result = gson.fromJson(response , Map.class);                                        //result.get("").getExcavatorInformation().getClass()
//noinspection HardCodedStringLiteral

ListDetailModel model = new ListDetailModel();
for (Map.Entry<String,ListDetailModel> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Log.d("++++++++++++++"," " +key);
    // do stuff
}
```

So lets say there is another CarDetailModel inside ListDetailModel, cannot I do something like entry.get("CarDetailModel").getKey() and retrieve those keys ?

Answer (score 0):

`Map.Entry<String,ListDetailModel>` is a node of the `Map<String,ListDetailModel>`.

You can only call `getKey()` or `getValue()` on it, not `get("CarDetailModel")`.

If you want to query a value in a Map by Key, then you have to call the function `get(Key k)` on the map itself, not on one of its Entries

Comment: So does it mean I have to make separate gson objects for every class to get its values ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without seeing your JSON. If your ListDetailModel IS:  a) a map itself or b) an object that contains another map then from an entry you would do:
a) entry.getValue().get("otherKey") or b) entry.getValue().getMapInstance().get("otherKey"). It entirely depends on the JSON object and how you want to represent the structure in your Class. The only thing that is guaranteed is that you cannot call get("key") on an Map.Entry object.

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON by Google rather than parsing yourself

For Demos: https://github.com/google/gson